# WebView init got Exception: Failed to create lock file webview_data.lock EACCES(Permission Denied)

Tags: android, webview, storage, filenotfoundexception

I got this exception on my Samsung Android 10 phone which on chromim80. The other device seems ok.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create lock file /data/user/0/my_package/app_webview/webview_data.lock
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3448)     
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)     
 android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)     
 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)     
 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)     
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)     
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)     
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)     
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)     
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)     
 com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)     
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)     

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create lock file /data/user/0/my_package/app_webview/webview_data.lock     
 org.chromium.android_webview.AwDataDirLock.b(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-428014130:31)     
 Mj.i(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-428014130:31)     
 Mj.b(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-428014130:16)     
 Mj.k(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-428014130:2)     
 com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.g(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-428014130:2)     
 com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-428014130:14)     
 android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:429)     
 android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:353)     
 android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:336)     
 android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:323)     
 android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:313)
```

My targetSDK is 29 and I have added `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` and `WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix(processName);` .

Does anyone know how to solve this problem？

**UPDATE:**

I found this so I think it is the reason. It only happened on chromim80.

https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/2153785/3/android_webview/java/src/org/chromium/android_webview/AwDataDirLock.java#70

For now it seems that all I can do is use webview only on main process.

Comment: Have u solve this exception already? I added requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in manifest, but it didn't work, I also found this exception on my Samsung Android 10. U said use webview only on main process, how cound u

Answer (score 1):

Android 9 prohibit sharing Web-view data directory among multiple processes. If one web-view is already using it then it wont be able to access it. Instead you can try this

```
 public void onCreate() {
    ...
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        String processName = getProcessName(this);
        String packageName = this.getPackageName();
        if (!packageName.equals(processName)) {
            WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix(processName);
        }
    }}

private String getProcessName(Context context) {
    if (context == null) return null;
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : manager.getRunningAppProcesses()) {
        if (processInfo.pid == android.os.Process.myPid()) {
            return processInfo.processName;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replay, but we already added WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix(processName);

Comment: @rajkavadia In my app there is no Webview.setDataDirectorySuffix. Shall i need to set the above in my app?